# scrolled percentage of a page, i have framed and written the javascript but it isnt working

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, scrollbar

I have a gallery of images, which contains a large number of images and I want the user to keep watch on how much he had seen.
For this, I create a bar in the top right corner containing the percentage that denotes how much the document has been viewed/scrolled.I am attaching the as far as i have done...
The final output i want is https://ninjasfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/0000000000001881.gif

```js
var scrolledBar = document.getElementById("scrolled");



// This function will return the maximum of the following 
function getDocHeight() {
    var D = document;
    return Math.max(
        D.body.scrollHeight, D.body.offsetHeight, D.body.clientHeight
    );
}



var docHeight = getDocHeight();
var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

window.onresize = function (e) {
    docHeight = getDocHeight();
    windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
};



// This function uses a for loop for individual progress bars. You can modify it so that it applies to the whole skill section at once
function setScrolled() {
    
    var scrolled = Math.floor((window.scrollY/(docHeight-windowHeight))*100);
    
    scrolledBar.innerText = scrolled;
    
}


document.addEventListener('scroll', function(){

    var h = document.documentElement, 
        b = document.body,
        st = 'scrollTop',
        sh = 'scrollHeight';

    var percent = (h[st]||b[st]) / ((h[sh]||b[sh]) - h.clientHeight) * 100;
    
    document.getElementById('scroll').textContent = 'scrolled: ' + percent + '%';
    
});
```

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 1vw;
    right: 1vw;
    font-size: 1rem;
}
#progress-bar {
    height: 30px;
    width: 20vw;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-align: center;
    color: #1b994d;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px grey, 0px 0px 5px green;
}
#progress-bar span {
    line-height: 30px;
}
#scrolled {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
}
#start {
    padding: 11px;
    width: 70%;
    text-align: justify;
    color: grey;
    line-height: 28px;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    margin: auto;
}

/* Portfolio Section */
#gallery h1 {
    color: #2857a4;
    margin-bottom: 74px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    word-spacing: 1vw;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
}
#gallery-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 0 50px 100px;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.gallery-image-container {
    max-width: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 30px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
}
.gallery-image-container img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.gallery-image-container:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #74ADC8;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Gallery</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"type="text/css"href="Percentage Scrolled.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="scroll">
   <header>
       <div id="progress-bar">
           <span><span id="scrolled">0</span>% Viewed</span>
       </div>
   </header>
    <div id="start">
        <p>
           One of the basic thing about <span class="text-highlight">typesetting industry</span>. is the industry's standard <span class="text-highlight">dummy text ever</span> since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s <span class="text-highlight">with the release of Letraset</span> sheets containing Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
    </div>

    <section id="gallery">
        <h1>Image Gallery</h1>

        <div id="gallery-container">

            <div class="gallery-image-container">
                <img src="https://ninjasfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/asset_0000000000000025_1550237330_codezen_2.png">
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-image-container">
                <img src="https://ninjasfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/asset_0000000000000025_1550237330_codezen_2.png">
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-image-container">
                <img src="https://ninjasfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/asset_0000000000000025_1550237330_codezen_2.png">
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-image-container">
                <img src="https://ninjasfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/asset_0000000000000024_1550237299_codezen.png">
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-image-container">
                <img src="https://ninjasfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/asset_0000000000000024_1550237299_codezen.png">
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-image-container">
                <img src="https://ninjasfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/asset_0000000000000024_1550237299_codezen.png">
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-image-container">
                <img src="https://ninjasfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/asset_0000000000000025_1550237330_codezen_2.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-image-container">
                <img src="https://ninjasfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/asset_0000000000000025_1550237330_codezen_2.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-image-container">
                <img src="https://ninjasfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/asset_0000000000000025_1550237330_codezen_2.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-image-container">
                <img src="https://ninjasfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/asset_0000000000000024_1550237299_codezen.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-image-container">
                <img src="https://ninjasfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/asset_0000000000000024_1550237299_codezen.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-image-container">
                <img src="https://ninjasfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/asset_0000000000000024_1550237299_codezen.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
    <scipt type="text/javascript"src="Percentage Scrolled.js"></scipt>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Gallery</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"type="text/css"href="Percentage Scrolled.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="scroll">
   <header>
       <div id="progress-bar">
           <span><span id="scrolled">0</span>% Viewed</span>
       </div>
   </header>
    <div id="start">
        <p>
           One of the basic thing about <span class="text-highlight">typesetting industry</span>. is the industry's standard <span class="text-highlight">dummy text ever</span> since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s <span class="text-highlight">with the release of Letraset</span> sheets containing Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
    </div>

    <section id="gallery">
        <h1>Image Gallery</h1>

        <div id="gallery-container">

            <div class="gallery-image-container">
                <img src="https://ninjasfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/asset_0000000000000025_1550237330_codezen_2.png">
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-image-container">
                <img src="https://ninjasfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/asset_0000000000000025_1550237330_codezen_2.png">
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-image-container">
                <img src="https://ninjasfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/asset_0000000000000025_1550237330_codezen_2.png">
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-image-container">
                <img src="https://ninjasfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/asset_0000000000000024_1550237299_codezen.png">
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-image-container">
                <img src="https://ninjasfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/asset_0000000000000024_1550237299_codezen.png">
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-image-container">
                <img src="https://ninjasfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/asset_0000000000000024_1550237299_codezen.png">
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-image-container">
                <img src="https://ninjasfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/asset_0000000000000025_1550237330_codezen_2.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-image-container">
                <img src="https://ninjasfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/asset_0000000000000025_1550237330_codezen_2.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-image-container">
                <img src="https://ninjasfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/asset_0000000000000025_1550237330_codezen_2.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-image-container">
                <img src="https://ninjasfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/asset_0000000000000024_1550237299_codezen.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-image-container">
                <img src="https://ninjasfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/asset_0000000000000024_1550237299_codezen.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-image-container">
                <img src="https://ninjasfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/asset_0000000000000024_1550237299_codezen.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
    <scipt type="text/javascript"src="Percentage Scrolled.js"></scipt>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
document.getElementById('scroll').textContent = 'scrolled: ' + percent + '%'; 
// the `#scroll` element is a <div> containing all the content on the page
```

with

```
document.getElementById('scrolled').textContent = Math.floor(percent);
// the `#scrolled` element is the <span> containing the percentage
```

You also have a typographic error in your `<script>` tag at the end of the HTML and the `src` file name has a space in it, which isn't allowed.

```
<scipt type="text/javascript"src="Percentage Scrolled.js"></scipt>
```

should be corrected to the following (and you'll need to rename your .js file to match)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Percentage-Scrolled.js"></script>
```

```js
var scrolledBar = document.getElementById("scrolled");

// This function will return the maximum of the following 
function getDocHeight() {
  var D = document;
  return Math.max(
    D.body.scrollHeight, D.body.offsetHeight, D.body.clientHeight
  );
}

var docHeight = getDocHeight();
var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
window.onresize = function (e) {
  docHeight = getDocHeight();
  windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
};

// This function uses a for loop for individual progress bars. You can modify it so that it applies to the whole skill section at once
function setScrolled() {
  var scrolled = Math.floor((window.scrollY / (docHeight - windowHeight)) * 100);
  scrolledBar.innerText = scrolled;
}

document.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
  var h = document.documentElement,
    b = document.body,
    st = 'scrollTop',
    sh = 'scrollHeight';
  var percent = (h[st] || b[st]) / ((h[sh] || b[sh]) - h.clientHeight) * 100;
  
  document.getElementById('scrolled').textContent = Math.floor(percent);
});
```

```css
body { font-family: sans-serif; } header { position: fixed; top: 1vw; right: 1vw; font-size: 1rem; } #progress-bar { height: 30px; width: 20vw; background-color: transparent; text-align: center; color: #1b994d; border-radius: 20px; box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px grey, 0px 0px 5px green; } #progress-bar span { line-height: 30px; } #scrolled { font-size: 1.3rem; } #start { padding: 11px; width: 70%; text-align: justify; color: grey; line-height: 28px; font-size: 1.1rem; margin: auto; } /* Portfolio Section */ #gallery h1 { color: #2857a4; margin-bottom: 74px; text-transform: uppercase; word-spacing: 1vw; text-align: center; font-size: 30px; } #gallery-container { display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; margin: 0 50px 100px; justify-content: space-around; } .gallery-image-container { max-width: 400px; overflow: hidden; margin: 30px; background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; position: relative; } .gallery-image-container img { width: 100%; height: 100%; } .gallery-image-container:hover { box-shadow: 0 0 20px #74ADC8; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <title>Gallery</title> <link rel="stylesheet"type="text/css"href="Percentage Scrolled.css"> </head> <body> <div id="scroll"> <header> <div id="progress-bar"> <span><span id="scrolled">0</span>% Viewed</span> </div> </header> <div id="start"> <p> One of the basic thing about <span class="text-highlight">typesetting industry</span>. is the industry's standard <span class="text-highlight">dummy text ever</span> since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s <span class="text-highlight">with the release of Letraset</span> sheets containing Lorem Ipsum. </p> </div> <section id="gallery"> <h1>Image Gallery</h1> <div id="gallery-container"> <div class="gallery-image-container">  <img src="https://ninjasfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/asset_0000000000000025_1550237330_codezen_2.png"> </div> <div class="gallery-image-container">  <img src="https://ninjasfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/asset_0000000000000025_1550237330_codezen_2.png"> </div> <div class="gallery-image-container">  <img src="https://ninjasfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/asset_0000000000000025_1550237330_codezen_2.png"> </div> <div class="gallery-image-container">  <img src="https://ninjasfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/asset_0000000000000024_1550237299_codezen.png"> </div> <div class="gallery-image-container">  <img src="https://ninjasfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/asset_0000000000000024_1550237299_codezen.png"> </div> <div class="gallery-image-container">  <img src="https://ninjasfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/asset_0000000000000024_1550237299_codezen.png"> </div> <div class="gallery-image-container">  <img src="https://ninjasfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/asset_0000000000000025_1550237330_codezen_2.png" /> </div> <div class="gallery-image-container">  <img src="https://ninjasfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/asset_0000000000000025_1550237330_codezen_2.png" /> </div> <div class="gallery-image-container">  <img src="https://ninjasfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/asset_0000000000000025_1550237330_codezen_2.png" /> </div> <div class="gallery-image-container">  <img src="https://ninjasfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/asset_0000000000000024_1550237299_codezen.png" /> </div> <div class="gallery-image-container">  <img src="https://ninjasfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/asset_0000000000000024_1550237299_codezen.png" /> </div> <div class="gallery-image-container">  <img src="https://ninjasfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/asset_0000000000000024_1550237299_codezen.png" /> </div> </div> </section> </div> <script type="text/javascript" src="Percentage-Scrolled.js"></script> </body> </html>
```

Comment: man its working here but as soon as i am coping it on vs cade its not working and as i have seen u havent used any jquery too. i just copied the whole program from here pls tell me why this is happening

Comment: You have a space in your script src, and you've misspelled `script` –  `<scipt type="text/javascript"src="Percentage Scrolled.js"></scipt>` should be `<script type="text/javascript"src="Percentage-Scrolled.js"></script>` (don't forget to rename the file to match).